# Decode data Uri PNG into RGBA monodimensional array using pako.js

Tags: javascript, png, zlib, data-uri, inflate

In a web page, coded in Javascript, I need to do pixel modification of a PNG image. In order to achieve it, I need first to have a pixel representation of my PNG. BUT The PNG Image is encapsulated in a data uri scheme.

I tried the following steps using a test image The image (5px,5px) of RGBA=255/0/0/20
But the monodimensional matrix I get is wrong.

Here's the piece of code:

```
var b64Data     = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAE0lEQVQIW2P8z8AgwoAGGGkgCABN
var strData     = atob(b64Data);
console.log("strData "+strData.length)
var charData    = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});
console.log("charData "+charData.length)
var binData= new Uint8Array(charData);
console.log("binData "+binData.length)
var data        = pako.inflate(binData.subarray(41));//41 in order to get the data chunk
console.log(data);
length = data.length
console.log('=============================');
for(i=1;i<length;i+=4){
    console.log(''+data[i]+'-'+data[i+1]+'-'+data[i+2]+'-'+data[i+3]);
}
```

but I end up with the following matrix in the console:

```
1-255-0-0-20
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
1-255-0-0
20-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-1-255-0
0-20-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-1-255
0-0-20-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-1
255-0-0-20
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
0-0-0-0
```

Why?

Comment: A better approach would be to set the data url as the `src` on an `img` tag, and then use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage` and `CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but no way: Canvas wouls apply pixel modification by alpha pre-multiplication.  I would end up with an array containing an array of RGBA 100/86/86/0 (I don't recall exactly the Blue en and Green Values)

Comment: Then get or make a real implementation of PNG decoding in javascript.  Even if you get it to work in this case, your hack of ignoring all of the headers and metadata and just blindly reading at a fixed offset into the file is fragile and will fail on many things.

Comment: I agree (for example I will need to concatenate chunks as soon as the image will get bigger), but this sample of code is a starting point: no way to go further in the decoding steps if I am not able to read a simple 5px^2 matrix :)  And btw I haven't found any javascript library that decode PNG from data uri scheme... do you know any?

Comment: Sounds exactly what I needed! I'll try it immediately. It's really hidden: never  found it via googling

Comment: Btw K3N congratulation for your project!